# break a for loop when a specific condition is satisfied and continue to next iteration R version 3.0.2 windows

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Hello everyone I am new to R and I am trying to create a loop using the following code :

```
   x<- rep(NA, 10)
  for(i in 1:10)  {
  +  x[i]<- 1+i 
  if(i==5) # when a specific condition is satisfied #
  x[i]<- 2 # i want the loop to continue this way #
  }
```

so the result will be something like : 2 3 4 5 6 2 2 2 2 2 
What I think is that i have to use break or next statement but i cannot understand their use.
Any suggestions . In addition I am looking for any relevant material to study ...Thanks in advance.
My code goes like this

```
set.seed(10)
x<- rep(NA, 20)
tmp<- rep(FALSE, 20)
for(i in 1:20) {
x[i]<- runif(1)
tmp<- x[i]<0.5
if(2 * sum(tmp) - i + 1 > 2) {
tmp[i]<- x[i]<0.2
} else {
tmp[i]<- x[i]<0.8
}
}
```

But i cannot make it work . In fact i want the possibility to switch to 0.2 when 2 * sum(tmp) - i + 1 > 2 condition is satisfied and switch to 0.8 when 2 * sum(tmp) - i + 1 < -2 condition is satisfied or vice versa.

My goal is to create a vector as following. Take a random x from random uniform(0,1) if x<0.5 then the vector takes value a else takes b . This continues until the number of a's-the number of b's > 2 at this point i want to change the possibility that a's and b's are assigned to the vector to 0.2 (if x<0.2 then a). This probability i want to change again if the number of b's - the number of a's > 2 to 0.8(if x<0.8 then a). However because i have random numbers i may have the above situation vice versa. (first b's-a's>2 then a's-b's>2) .finally sth like vector<- a,b,a,a,a,b,b,a –
Hello again. Using your help i finally managed to get close to my goal but i still have a problem. Here is the code :

```
n1<- 0
n2<- 0
n<- 20
f<- rep(NA,20)
set.seed(10) 
d<- function(n){
x<- runif(20,0,1)
for(i in 1:20) {
if((n1-n2)<=2) {
f[i]<- ifelse(x[i]<0.5, 'a', 'b')
} else if((n1-n2)>2) { 
f[i]<- ifelse(x[i]<0.2, 'a', 'b')
} else if((n2-n1)>2) {
f[i]<- ifelse(x[i]<0.8, 'a', 'b')
} 
if(f[i]=='a')  {
n1<- n1 + 1 
} else  { 
n2<- n2 + 1
print(data.frame(f,x))
print(n1)
print(n2)
}
}
}
d(20)
```

and the rusults are

```
   f          x
1  b 0.50747820
2  a 0.30676851
3  a 0.42690767
4  b 0.69310208
5  a 0.08513597
6  a 0.22543662
7  a 0.27453052
8  b 0.27230507
9  b 0.61582931
10 a 0.42967153
11 b 0.65165567
12 b 0.56773775
13 a 0.11350898
14 b 0.59592531
15 a 0.35804998
16 a 0.42880942
17 a 0.05190332
18 b 0.26417767
19 a 0.39879073
20 b 0.83613414
```

In line seven as you can see a's-b-s=5-2=3 and thus in line 8 the sampling probability for a has been changed to 0.2. And here is my problem. I want from now to keep sampling with this probability until or when b's-a's>2 and the probability should be changed to 0.8. This means that in line ten where the runif number is >0.2 i should have b and not a. Can you help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not very clearly explaining your goal. What does "But i cannot make it work" mean? Your code runs without error. Whatever your goal is, you probably don't need a `for` loop.

Comment: My goal is to create a vector as following. Take a random x from random uniform(0,1) if x<0.5 then the vector takes value a else takes b . This continues until the number of a's-the number of b's > 2 at this point i want to change the possibility that a's and b's are assigned to the vector to 0.2 (if x<0.2 then a). This probability i want to change again if the number of b's - the number of b'a > 2 to  0.8(if x<0.8 then a). However because i have random numbers i may have the above situation vice versa. (first b's-a's>2 then a's-b's>2) .finally sth like vector<- a,b,a,a,a,b,b,a

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
x<- rep(NA, 10)
for(i in 1:10)  {
  if(i<5){
    x[i]<- 1+i 
  } else{
    x[i]<- 2
  }
}

> x
 [1] 2 3 4 5 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Nevertheless, you don't need a `for` loop to get your desired output, try `ifelse` instead:

```
> x <- 1:10
> ifelse(x<5, x+1, 2)
 [1] 2 3 4 5 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: or `x <- rep(1,10); y <- c(cumsum(x[1:5])+1,x[-(1:5)]+1)`

Comment: Thank you for your help . Actually i meant to use this as a guide to create a little more complicated loop. I am going to update my question...

Answer (score 0):

You really need to work on explaining yourself more clearly. I hope I interpreted your last comment correctly.

You don't need `runif` here, you can simply pass probabilities to `sample`:

```
#random seed for reproducibility
set.seed(42)
#possible values
vals <- c("a", "b")
#number of result values
n <- 1e5
#pre-allocate result vector
res <- character(n)
#numbers of first and second value
n1 <- 0
n2 <- 0
#probability
p <- 0.5
#loop
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  #if difference between number of value1 and value2
  #is greater than 2
  #change the probability for sampling the value that is present in lower numbers
  #to 0.2 and the other to 0.8
  if (abs(n1-n2) > 2) {
    p <- (n1>n2)*0.2 + (n1<n2)*0.8
  }
  #sample a value with the given probabilities
  res[i] <- sample(vals, 1, prob=c(p, 1-p))  
  #increase counter
  if (res[i]==vals[1]) n1 <- n1 + 1 else n2 <- n2 + 1
}
head(res, 20)
#[1] "a" "a" "b" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "a" "b" "a" "a" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a"
table(res)
# res
#     a     b 
# 49999 50001
```

**Edit:**

Let me demonstrate that you can replicate the result of `sample` with `runif`:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(c("a", "b"), 20, TRUE)
set.seed(42)
y <- ifelse(runif(20)<0.5, "a", "b")

identical(x, y)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Roland! That's exactly what i want. You are right i have to work on explaining myself. I am really new to R i started learning 3 months ago and i know i have a lot of work to do. Can you suggest me any material i could study on sampling with R? Anything it could be very helpful to me . Thanks again.

Comment: One last question . I want values a,b to be related to uniform(0,1) . This means that i want sampling with the given possibilities but every a or b be must depend on a random uniform number . For example if the sample possibility is 0.2 the character 'a' should be assigned to the vector if the random uniform number is  <0.2 . Should i sample the values from the uniform distribution?

Comment: You still haven't understood the principle behind `sample`. Apparently you are still trying to re-implement `sample` manually. You don't need the uniform distribution.

Comment: I think you are right . However, What in fact I am trying to do is to reproduce a specific randomization technique which uses random numbers from the uniform distribution (0,1).

Comment: Drawing numbers from the uniform distribution is the most basic random number generator. Most other randomizers can be derived from this. You are free to implement them yourself (and in some languages you might have to), but in R others already have done that for you. And what you describe you can achieve with `sample`. I suggest to take some time and think about what I have shown in my answer.

Comment: This means if i got it that sample(c('a', 'b'), 1, prob(0.5,0.5)) is  equal to x<- runif(0,1)

Comment: This means if i got it that sample(c('a', 'b',1 , prob=c(0.5,0.5)) is equal to x<- runif(1,0,1) if(x<0.5) then 'a' else 'b'? I apologize for being so annoying I did thought about your thorough answer but i couldnt understand how sample function works. From the relevant help page i didn't realize that it is related to the uniform  distribution and i am still searching the web to find anything relevant .

Comment: Yes it definitely helped. Now i realized how sample function works . Thanks again your help was very important to me.